# Should my ES6 class methods return a promise, even if not necessary?

Tags: javascript, class, language-agnostic, promise, es6-promise

I am writing an ES6 class that will hold a game instance. It has about 20 methods and half of them are calling asynchronous functions. It also has methods where the return value is computed immediately. That means that sometimes I need to return a `Promise` and sometimes I don't.

Now I am thinking about changing the remaining methods to also return `Promise`s.

> Advantage:    A more uniform style of dealing with callbacks/return values
>
> Disadvantage: Need to handle `Promise`s when not always necessary. Means a little overhead.

To me, both variants seem fine. Which one should I use, respecting readability and ease of use for potential developer colleagues?

Answer (score 1):

You return a promise if your operation is always asynchronous or is sometimes asynchronous.

But, if your method is always synchronous, then returning a promise just complicates the caller's use of the method and makes it more difficult to use your API.  It also slows things down a bit because promises are always resolved on a future tick.  And, making a synchronous operation into an async operation can create race conditions where none need exist (all depends upon the callers code).

In addition, the caller should generally have an understanding of which methods are asynchronous and which are not - I would not consider it an advantage to hide that from the caller.

So, in my mind synchronous APIs are simply easier to use so if the API is naturally synchronous, then you don't want to make it unnecessarily asynchronous.  And, remember that a synchronous function can always be used in the middle of a promise chain without modification.  But, it can be used by itself without a promise chain which is a developer usability advantage.

The naming and documentation for your API should make it very clear which operations are async that return a promise and which do not and return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Making every synchronous call into an asynchronous one is a terrible idea, because you lose the main guarantee of synchronous single-threaded programming in JavaScript:

- Nothing can muck with state in the background.

This is why you don't need locks in JavaScript. You can call a synchronous function, and have deterministic expectations about what it can and can't change, provided you avoid global variables (which are bad for the same reason).

Contrast this with an asynchronous call, where by the time it returns, state may have changed any number of ways.

This is the reason for the `await` keyword in ES7/8:

```
async function foo(bar) {
  if (bar.value == 3) {
    let result1 = syncFunction("three");

    // bar.value is 3 here guaranteed, provided sub-functions can't access it

    let result2 = await asyncFunction("three");

    // bar.value (and everything) may have changed by the time we get here.  

    let result3 = syncFunction2("three"); // bug

    return [result1, result2, result3];
  }
}
```

See http://calculist.org/blog/2011/12/14/why-coroutines-wont-work-on-the-web/ for the full story.